# as ... so (do) (too)

Tags: word-usage

1. > The Cold War dominated the international agenda in the world, and the
   >   democratization dominated every social agenda at that time in South Korea.
2. > The English love soccer, and the Americans love baseball.

Below I've reworded these sentences to use the "as ... so" construction. Are my sentences correct?

1. > **(Just) as** the Cold War dominated the international agenda in the world,
   >   **so (too)** did the democratization every social agenda at that time in
   >   South Korea.
2. > **(Just) as** the English love soccer, **so (too)** do the Americans
   >   baseball.

Answer (score 1):

Even when you add "just as... so too..." you should leave the verb in place.

> Just as the Cold War dominated the international agenda in the world, so too did the democratization **dominate** every social agenda at that time in South Korea.

Also, adding those words implies a parallel meaning, whereas "and" just implies that they are both facts.

> The Cold War dominated the international agenda in the world

and

> The democratization dominated every social agenda at that time in South Korea

are not parallel because "the democratization" refers back to the meaning of the first clause.  That is, unless there were some other statement earlier about the democratization of South Korea, and the use in this sentence was referring back to that.  We would have to know more about what came earlier in the passage to answer that question.

The second example is fine with the adjusted structure, but again, the verb has to remain:

> Just as the English love soccer, so too do the Americans **love** baseball

I would merely note with levity that Americans probably don't love baseball as much as the English love soccer.

Comment: That was all I wanted to know, If it's possible to omit the *verbs* of the 2nd clause in such as..so sentences containing subject>verb>object form  like the ones in question , however in sentences  formed with only >subject and >verb it's pretty normal like ; ***Just as George W. Bush betrayed his foolish followers, so must Obama.***